# How can javascript object method refer to variable that is not declared yet?

Tags: javascript

I'm reading this js [tutorial](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/javascript-the-core-2nd-edition/), in `Def. 5: Class` section there's a code snippet:

```
// Generic prototype for all letters.
let letter = {
  getNumber() {
    return this.number;
  }
};
```

I wonder how can `getNumber` method refer to `number` which is not declared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`number` isn't a variable, it's a property. You don't have to declare properties (in fact, until the [class fields proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) progresses [it's currently at [Stage 3]](https://tc39.github.io/process-document/), you *can't* declare properties; there's no property declaration syntax, just a property *initialization* syntax). Variables are storage outside of an object.¹ A property is storage within an object.

If you're wondering how `getNumber` can use the property before it's created, it's because that's just how JavaScript is defined: Trying to get the value of a property that doesn't exist results in the value `undefined`, not an error.

---

¹ *"...outside of an object."* At least, as far as your code is concerned. In specification terms, variables are *bindings* (which are very similar to properties) within a *lexical environment object*, but that's a specification thing, not something you can directly use in code.

Comment: Thanks I typed `letter.getNumber()` in chrome console and it indeed returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `this.number` is `letter.number` which is not defined. And, it means it is evaluted as `undefined`.

```
var obj = {};
obj.number; // undefined
```

Comment: Thanks for your time! Unfortunately I can only accept one answer but I upvoted yours, keep up the good work!